# Access control from .aspx in .ascx

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I have a custom user control that I made called `OrderForm.ascx`. I also have an `.aspx` file that utilizes the `OrderForm` control.

I want to access a control on the `.aspx` file from the `OrderForm` control. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So just to understand, you have 2 web controls on a page and you want control 1 to be able to access a value from control 2?

Comment: I have a label on my .aspx page. I want to access that label in my .ascx control - which i also add to the .aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `FindControl` method in the user control like this:

```
Label label = Page.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
if (label != null)
    string labelText = label.Text;
```

As a note on the above, depending on where the Label is in the page, you may need to use recursion to find the Label.

You could also create a property on the page that returns the text of the Label:

```
public string LabelText
{
    get { return Label1.Text; }
}
```

To access the property from the user control, here are two options:

Option #1

```
string labelText = ((PageName)Page).LabelText;
```

Option #2

```
string labelText = Page.GetType().GetProperty("LabelText").GetValue(Page, null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two user controls, ControlA and ControlB, and they are both registered on the same page you can easily access one from the other. Simply create a public property that you want to have access to in ControlB such as:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ControlB_DDL() As DropDownList
    Get
        Return Me.ddlItems
    End Get
End Property
```

And then you can reference that property in ControlA after finding that control:

```
ControlB ctrlB = (ControlB)Page.FindControl("cB");
DropDownList ddl = ctrlB.ControlB_DDL;
```

Refer here for more info: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155

Answer (score -1):

To access the controls of .ascx in .aspx.

```
HiddenField selectedEmailsId = performanceReportCtrl.FindControl("CONTROLID") as HiddenField;
```

And to access controls of aspx in ascx.

```
HiddenField selectedEmailsId = Page.FindControl("CONTROLID") as HiddenField;
```